# how to access value json object in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I have a json file that is down code:

```
{"fileContent":[{"name":"directorffdsgfg","type":"file","ext":"sql","modified":"2013\/04\/11 - 10:00","created":"2013\/04\/11 - 10:00","size":"1577"},{"name":"directory02","type":"file","ext":"sql","modified":"2013\/04\/11 - 12:10","created":"2013\/04\/11 - 12:10","size":"1577"},{"name":"jquery-mousewheel-master","type":"file","ext":"zip","modified":"2013\/04\/11 - 12:10","created":"2013\/04\/11 - 12:10","size":"5213"}],"folderContent":[{"name":"Folder 2","type":"folder","ext":"sql","modified":"2013\/04\/11 - 05:04","created":"2013\/04\/11 - 05:04","size":"1577"},{"name":"Folder 1","type":"folder","ext":"zip","modified":"2013\/04\/15 - 09:08","created":"2013\/04\/15 - 09:08","size":"11867"}],"files":9,"folders":2}
```

I want to know that what access value in object json. (for example I want access to value of files , folders , fileContent , folderContent)

I dont know about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON is a dictionary, and you can use NSJSONSerialization to convert this string to a dictionary:

```
NSData *jsonData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:nil];
```

then you can access properties by key, so to get the folder content array:

```
NSArray *folderContent = [json objectForKey:@"folderContent"];
```